# jQuery nested DOM selector

Tags: jquery, dom, selector

Let say I have the following HTML elements:

```
<div id="id">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="second"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering why this doesn't work in `jQuery`:

```
$("#id.first.second").click( // do some stuff ...
```

I usually use something like the following which works fine, but today I just found out that the above example is not working.

```
// working example
$("#id .second").click( // do some stuff ...
```

**Update:** My question is why it is not working without spaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selector `#id.first.second` means "an element with the `id` value `"id"` which *also* has the classes `first` and `second`".

Your second selector `#id .second` (with the space before `.second`) means "an element with the `id` value `"id"` which has a *descendant* element with class `second`". It's a "descendant selector".

So if you want to specify each of the three levels, you'd do this:

```
$("#id .first .second").click(...
```

...which means "an element with the `id` value `"id"` which has a *descendant* element with the class `first` which, in turn, has a *descendant* element with class `second`".

Or alternately, you might do:

```
$("#id > .first > .second").click(...
```

...which means "an element with the `id` value `"id"` which has a *direct child* element with the class `first` which, in turn, has a *direct child* element with class `second`. It's a *child selector* (actually two of them).

Or, of course, some combination of them.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
$("#id .first .second").click( // do some stuff ...
```

For your first selector it would be searching for:

```
<div id="id" class="first second">
</div>
```

**Explanation**

Your first selector is looking for an element with an id `id` having classes `first` and `second`.

But you actually want to look for an element with class `second` beeing a descendant of an element with class `first`, which is again a descendant of an element with id `id`

Comment: Correct. The original selector doesn't work in jQuery because it doesn't work in CSS.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The original selector doesn't work because it doesn't match the DOM structure of the page. Is that what you meant? Saying it "doesn't work in CSS" is incorrect because it *is* a valid selector (just not for any element on their page).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Yes, that's what I mean: it doesn't work as the OP expects. jQuery selectors are based on CSS selectors.

Comment: I don't think that this is a 100% correct description. jQuery selectors are baseb on the Sizzle engine (http://sizzlejs.com/) which supports virtually all CSS 3 Selectors: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation

Answer (score 1):

A space between selector means **"any descendant of"**: direct children and children of those children could be selected.

So `$('#id .first .second')` this means get the `DOM` inside `div` with id of id and get descendent `DOM` with `class` name of **first** and its descendent `DOM` with `class` name of **second**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [jQuery descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)  selector here. You need to give a space between the parent selector and the child.

If you specify the sectors without space it will be considered as a and condition. In your case it will look for an element with id `id` and has the classes `first` and `second`. ex: `<div id="id" class="first second"></div>`

`$("#id.first.second")` should be `$("#id .first .second")`

Answer (score 0):

Put spaces between them:

```
$("#id .first .second").click( // do some stuff ...
```

### See:

`$("#id.first.second").click( // do some stuff ...`

what this is looking for an id with some classes, something like:

```
<div id='id' class='first second'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the selectors by a space to find descendants.

```
$("#id .first .second").click(function(){
   alert("Hello");
});
```

The original selector tried to find an element with and id of `id` class of `first` and a class of `second`.